# Finding multiple occurrences of dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use most simple way to count all occurrences of x dictionary but without result.
I cant import any library, nor use other statments than: for var in, if x, if not, if is.

Result of script should look like this:
example:

```
list = [1,2,1,'a',4,2,3,3,5,'a',2]

code

print occurrences(list)

result

1 = [0, 2]
2 = [1, 5, 10]
a = [3, 9]
and so on
```

@edited
corrected text

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyourtried.com) Also, please clarify your question - what are cicles?

Comment: i meant "if statment" and "for statment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, without using any library or function:

```
lis = [1,2,1,'a',4,2,3,3,5,'a',2]
dic={}
index=0
for item in lis:
    if item in dic:
        dic[item]+=[index]
        index+=1
    else:
        dic[item]=[index] 
        index+=1
print dic
```

**output:**

```
{'a': [3, 9], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1, 5, 10], 3: [6, 7], 4: [4], 5: [8]}
```

Comment: why are u using 2x index +=1 in both cases?
@edit
only add in "if" and delete in "else"

Comment: `enumerate` is more convenient way then manually calculating of `index`.

Comment: I was trying use str.index() but it was returning me only first index and ignored all rest...
could u be so kind to show me an example with enumerate, please?

Comment: @user1768615 See my answer for this question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13033040/523217).

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev I know what `enumerate()` does, I just wanted to a show a solution without using any functions or libraries.

Comment: @user1768615 well `index+=1` is needed in both cases otherwise, the program will return an incorrect output.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l = [1,2,1,'a',4,2,3,3,5,'a',2]
>>> pos = {}
>>> for i, n in enumerate(l):
...     pos.setdefault(n, []).append(i)
... 
>>> pos
{'a': [3, 9], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1, 5, 10], 3: [6, 7], 4: [4], 5: [8]}
>>> for k, v in pos.items():
...     print "%s = %s" % (k, v)
... 
a = [3, 9]
1 = [0, 2]
2 = [1, 5, 10]
3 = [6, 7]
4 = [4]
5 = [8]
```

Comment: nice soluction of problem.
could u explaind me of using 2x variables, "i,n", please?

Comment: @user1768615 `enumerate` will return you iterator with tuples `(position, element)` (`[(0,1), (1,2), (2,1), ...]`). `i,n` syntax is just a multiple assignment: position to `i`, element to `n`.

Comment: isnt more simple use range() in place of enumerate?

Comment: @user1768615 Definitely not. `range` will create separated list and will allocate memory for this. `enumerate` iterator is created specially for such cases, so I don't see any disadvantages of using it.

Comment: Thank you very but very much =)
pfff, i cant make 2 answer as right one =/